# chart does not plot line(s) from google sheet data

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to update some legacy charts on a site to work with v4 google api, which previously worked with the v3 api.

I have the following JS code fragment that renders a chart but with no plot lines:

```
<hr /><div id="highcharts-APP_barack_obama">&nbsp;</div><script>
(function() {
  var files = ["https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js", "https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js", "https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-3d.js", "https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js", "https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js", "https://code.highcharts.com/modules/funnel.js", "https://code.highcharts.com/modules/annotations.js", "https://code.highcharts.com/modules/solid-gauge.js"],
    loaded = 0;
  if (typeof window["HighchartsEditor"] === "undefined") {
    window.HighchartsEditor = {
      ondone: [cl],
      hasWrapped: false,
      hasLoaded: false
    };
    include(files[0]);
  } else {
    if (window.HighchartsEditor.hasLoaded) {
      cl();
    } else {
      window.HighchartsEditor.ondone.push(cl);
    }
  }

  function isScriptAlreadyIncluded(src) {
    var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName("script");
    for (var i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++) {
      if (scripts[i].hasAttribute("src")) {
        if ((scripts[i].getAttribute("src") || "").indexOf(src) >= 0 || (scripts[i].getAttribute("src") === "http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js" && src === "https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js")) {
          return true;
        }
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  function check() {
    if (loaded === files.length) {
      for (var i = 0; i < window.HighchartsEditor.ondone.length; i++) {
        try {
          window.HighchartsEditor.ondone[i]();
        } catch (e) {
          console.error(e);
        }
      }
      window.HighchartsEditor.hasLoaded = true;
    }
  }

  function include(script) {
    function next() {
      ++loaded;
      if (loaded < files.length) {
        include(files[loaded]);
      }
      check();
    }
    if (isScriptAlreadyIncluded(script)) {
      return next();
    }
    var sc = document.createElement("script");
    sc.src = script;
    sc.type = "text/javascript";
    sc.onload = function() {
      next();
    };
    document.head.appendChild(sc);
  }

  function each(a, fn) {
    if (typeof a.forEach !== "undefined") {
      a.forEach(fn);
    } else {
      for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (fn) {
          fn(a[i]);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  var inc = {},
    incl = [];
  each(document.querySelectorAll("script"), function(t) {
    inc[t.src.substr(0, t.src.indexOf("?"))] = 1;
  });

  function cl() {
    if (typeof window["Highcharts"] !== "undefined") {
      var options = {
        "title": {
          "text": "Barack Obama Approval Ratings"
        },
        "subtitle": {
          "text": "2009-2017"
        },
        "exporting": {},
        "yAxis": [{
          "title": {
            "text": "Approval Rating"
          },
          "labels": {}
        }],
        "series": [{
          "name": "Approving"
        }, {
          "name": "Disapproving"
        }, {
          "name": "Unsure/NoData"
        }],
        "chart": {},
        "xAxis": [{
          "title": {
            "text": "Years"
          },
          "labels": {}
        }],
        "plotOptions": {
          "series": {
            "dataLabels": {}
          }
        },
        "tooltip": {
          "shared": true
        },
        "credits": {
          "text": "The American Presidency Project"
        },
        "data": {
          "googleSpreadsheetKey": "1iEl565M1mICTubTtoxXMdxzaHzAcPTnb3kpRndsrfyY",
          "googleSpreadsheetRange": "Barack Obama!A2:E500",
          "dataRefreshRate": false,
          "enablePolling": true,
          "googleAPIKey": "***********************************"
        }
      };

      new Highcharts.Chart("highcharts-APP_barack_obama", options);
    }
  }
})();
</script><p><a class="btn btn-default" href="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iEl565M1mICTubTtoxXMdxzaHzAcPTnb3kpRndsrfyY/edit?usp=sharing">View Data Sheet</a></p><hr />
```

I am getting a valid JSON response from Google Sheets that is of the form:

```
{
  "range": "'Barack Obama'!A2:E500",
  "majorDimension": "COLUMNS",
  "values": [
    [
      "1/16/17",
      "1/9/17",
      "1/2/17",
      "12/26/16",
      "12/19/16",
...
    ],
    [
      "1/19/2017",
      "1/15/2017",
      "1/8/2017",
      "1/1/2017",
      "12/25/2016",
...
    ],
    [
      59,
      57,
      55,
      55,
      56,
...
    ],
    [
      37,
      39,
      42,
      40
...
    ],
    [
      4,
      4,
      3,
      5,
...
    ]
  ]
}
```

But I am getting an error #14 from either highcharts.js or highstock.js in the browser console:

```
highcharts.src.js:224 Uncaught Error: Highcharts error #14: www.highcharts.com/errors/14/
    at Object.<anonymous> (highcharts.src.js:224)
    at B (highcharts.src.js:1668)
    at r (highcharts.src.js:246)
    at n.a.setData (highcharts.src.js:36457)
    at n.a.update (highcharts.src.js:38685)
    at highcharts.src.js:32499
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at highcharts.src.js:32482
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at a.update (highcharts.src.js:32470)
(anonymous) @ highcharts.src.js:224
B @ highcharts.src.js:1668
r @ highcharts.src.js:246
a.setData @ highcharts.src.js:36457
a.update @ highcharts.src.js:38685
(anonymous) @ highcharts.src.js:32499
(anonymous) @ highcharts.src.js:32482
a.update @ highcharts.src.js:32470
a.afterComplete @ data.src.js:2170
b.complete @ data.src.js:2141
b.dataFound @ data.src.js:999
b.init @ data.src.js:859
b.update @ data.src.js:2175
(anonymous) @ highcharts.src.js:32447
I @ highcharts.src.js:1316
a.update @ highcharts.src.js:32444
(anonymous) @ data.src.js:1675
success @ data.src.js:1642
e.onreadystatechange @ data.src.js:113
highcharts.src.js:230 Highcharts warning #15: www.highcharts.com/errors/15/
```

Is there something I'm overtly doing wrong here? I added the GoogleAPIKey and updated the legacy embed fragment to use the googleSpreadsheetRange value as opposed to Start, End parameters as I needed a way to select the Sheet in Google v4 API and the SheetNumber was deprecated.

Any feedback is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you describe is already on the GitHub ticket and is listed as resolved.
https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/16210

Here is a PR for this issue:
https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/pull/16232

API References:
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/data.googleSpreadsheetRange

```
data: {
    googleAPIKey: 'AIzaSyCQ0Jh8OFRShXam8adBbBcctlbeeA-qJOk',
    googleSpreadsheetKey: '0AoIaUO7wH1HwdENPcGVEVkxfUDJkMmFBcXMzOVVPdHc',
    googleSpreadsheetRange: "'Fruit Consumption'",
    error: console.error
}
```

Demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/8cktapse/

Comment: hi thanks for your reply. Is the PR fully submitted and released? because my code is using the latest production code from the src urls such as: `hhtps://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js` and I was still seeing the error last week, and the PR and fixes are from Aug 24 of this year ...

Comment: I updated post, I think everything works under v4 with this demo and a new googleSpreadsheetRange property has been added to the documentation.